# Key double press doesn't work

Tags: keyboard

When I press any key on my keyboard multiple times only the first one takes effect if the delay between pressing is less than about 300ms. Pressing different keys works, problem is only with the same key being pressed multiple times.

It happens in all windows, terminal, all keyboard layouts etc.

It is quite annoying, I tried Ubuntu update and restart.

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, 64bit
GNOME 3.28.2

Answer (score 4):

Go to Settings -> Universal Access -> Typing -> Typing Assist (AccessX)  and turn off "Bounce Keys" setting.

Comment: Unfortunately «Bounce Keys» is already off. Any more ideas?

Comment: Maybe that is a problem with the Dell laptop (the Fn key also doesn't work) :(

Comment: I had this problem with my hp elitebook. Now, resolved!